# How do I get the dropdown menu to see all the functions in vs2008 When using VBSCRIPT

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vbscript, intellisense

I wanted to know how do get the dropdown menu that shows all the function so I can browse easily between them in visual studio 2008 when coding in vbscript. I have it in C++ but I have no idea of how to get it to show for VBScript.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The bad news**: VBScript intellisense has been [disabled in Visual Studio 2008](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/290845/no-intellisense-and-color-coding-for-classic-asp-in-vs2008-beta-2):

> [...] We are depcrecting VB Script colorization and intellisense support in Visual Studio 2008. We recommend to customers to use VS 2005 or VWD 2005 to edit VB Script. Those products can be installed on the same machine as VS 2008 without any issues.  - Visual Web Developer Team

**The good news**: This caused a lot of people to complain, so the Visual Web Developer Team decided to [reenable VBScript support in Visual Studio 2008 SP1](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/292379/unintelligible-where-is-vbscript-support):

> We have enabled VBScript intellisense and colorization and it will be supported with the next roll-up patch/SP.

So, you have to install SP1 for Visual Studio 2008.